# Groovy Script Decimal vs. Whole Numbers

Tags: javascript, groovy, soapui

This is more of an elementry SoapUI Groovy Scdript Question.

In a Response that returns 100.000
I'm to assert that my return value is < the Response

If I do:

```
max = 100
resonse = ('${responseTC#xyz..."')

assert resposne < max
```

"Error is (java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

I have found some ways around this but I want to ask you experts - the "expert" way of handling this.

Thank you,
Rob

Comment: In SoapUI, a simple assertion like that can be done using an XPath assertion, which does not worry about type-casting.

Answer (score 0):

the most natural and "expert" way is:

```
int max = 100
def response = responseString.toFloat()
assert max > response
```

Comment: THANK YOU - i never used "float" before - I'll have to read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Also in soapUI I now used toDouble() or toBigDecimal() at the end of the context.expand.  I did not have to use "int" for any hard coded value.  I'm still learning but it seems when you get responses w/ decimal values - asserting is annoying.  Sometimes I need to round() the #.

I created this tester script assertion (all the toFloat(), as Int, even applying no method to the def context Failed on me).  Even if they passed an == assertion, I couldn't do MATH on them sub/add etc.

So far I see the safe way is toBigDecimal() & toDouble().

```
/* Look at the end of each 'def'----notice the method
*  Each def line is the same exact response value
*  the ending method will re-translate how the computer/ SoapUI looks at this numerical value.  If using this code - replace my def context.expand w/ one of your own.
*/

def householdMAGI_toBigDec = context.expand( '${Addition_Subtraction2#Response#declare namespace ns2=\'http://something.com/\'; //ns2:QhpDResponse[1]/QhpDResponse[1]/TaxHouseholdEligibility[1]/HouseholdMagi[1]}' ).toBigDecimal()
log.info ("toBigDecimal:  "+householdMAGI_toBigDec) //  '45210.56'

def householdMAGI_toDouble = context.expand( '${Addition_Subtraction2#Response#declare namespace ns2=\'http://something.com/\'; //ns2:QhpDResponse[1]/QhpDResponse[1]/TaxHouseholdEligibility[1]/HouseholdMagi[1]}' ).toDouble()
log.info ("toDouble:  "+householdMAGI_toDouble) //  '45210.56''

/*Here we are going to define the same number ourselves manually in various ways
 * Below under each def - one at at time remove the // from an assertiong and run the script
 * The results are already noted after each assertion
 */
def magi_a = 45210.56

assert householdMAGI_toBigDec == magi_a     //---PASSES (When set toBigDecimal()
assert householdMAGI_toDouble == magi_a     //---PASSES (When set toDouble()

calc_magi_a1 = magi_a + householdMAGI_toBigDec
log.info ("calc_magi_a1:  "+calc_magi_a1)   //---Successful Addition
calc_magi_a2 = magi_a + householdMAGI_toDouble
log.info ("calc_magi_a2:  "+calc_magi_a2)   //---Successful Addition
```